# How to uninstall ImageMagick completely and reinstall it in a right way?

Tags: 14.04, imagemagick

I am trying to uninstall `ImageMagick` using `sudo make uninstall` command  but it is not working.

It's showing this error : `No rule to make target`uninstall'.  Stop.`

How can i uninstall and reinstall ImageMagick??

Comment: How did you install ImageMagick in the first place?

Comment: it was installed by someone not by me. i newly got this system. :( @Takkat

Comment: @Nani `apt-cache policy imagemagick` should provide helpful output to determine how it was installed. But I am 99% sure that it was installed through the package manager.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command `sudo make uninstall` should only works if you install ImageMagick from sources.
In this case, you must run this command from the main directory of the sources.

But it was probably installed from the Ubuntu Software Center. So you could try :

```
sudo apt-get remove imagemagick
```

Or directly from the Ubuntu Software Center 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just did `sudo apt-get remove imagemagick` and it removed cups as a dependency.  I had to interrupt it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), but afterwards needed to recover with `sudo apt-get install cups cups-filters calibre`

I just hope my printer definitions are still there.